# Ajax pass prompt input to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, prompt

A form is dynamically created with PHP loop and presents one row from DB. I'm asking a user for input through prompt when he changes qty, but when I send it with AJAX to PHP it's empty. I guess it's because hidden input "new_message" is filled at the same time AJAX is sending values to PHP script so at that moment is blank. For the first row generated I get a message, but not for any other row.

Can you help me how to pass prompt input to PHP script?

```js
//Update qty on article    
$('.update_qty').on('change', function() {

  var message = prompt("Upišite razlog za izmjenu količine:");
  //e.preventDefault();

  //Get message value
  $('#new_message').val(message);

  var data = $('#form1').serializeArray();

  if (message != "" || message != NULL) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'update_qty.php',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Empty");
    e.PreventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<tbody>
<?php if (!empty($sales_plan_list)) {
      foreach($sales_plan_list as $sales_key => $sales_value) {
 ?>
<tr class="new">
   <td>
   <a href="view_product_sales.php?id=<?php echo $sales_value['article_id']; ?>">
   <?php echo $sales_value['article_no']; ?>
   </a>
   </td>
   <td><?php echo $sales_value['description']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo myNumberFormat($sales_value['rrp']); ?></td>
   <td>
   <form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="update_qty.php">
   <input type="text" name="update_qty" class="update_qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo $sales_value['qty'] ?>"><?php echo ' Kom'; ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="article_id" id="article_id" value="<?php echo $sales_value['article_id']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="sales_plan_id" id="sales_plan_id" value="<?php echo $sales_plan_id; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="product_mix_id" id="product_mix_id" value="<?php echo $product_mix_id; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="new_message" id="new_message" value="">
   </form>
   </td>
   <td>
   <a href="view_product_sales.php?id=<?php echo $sales_value['article_id']; ?>" class="ti-eye" title="Pogledaj"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="edit_product_sales.php?id=<?php echo $sales_value['article_id']; ?>" class="ti-settings" title="Izmjeni"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="delete_product_sales.php?id=<?php echo $sales_value['article_id']; ?>$sales_plan_id=<?php echo $sales_plan_id; ?>" class="ti-trash" title="Obriši"></a>
  </td>
   </tr>
   <?php
   }
   }
   ?>                                                                    
   </tbody>
```

Comment: Well serialize the form data _after_ you filled the field then …?

Comment: Like in the code above (which I edited)? That is also not working. Only can get a message for the first row.

Comment: What “rows” are you talking about in the first place? You talk about a loop, but neglected to show us said loop - so we can’t know what your generated from will look like. But IDs must be unique within an HTML document, so if your loop outputs what you have shown above multiple times, that would be wrong to begin with, and would be the first thing you need to fix.

Comment: Print data in php and check if there are the values. If not before sending ajax print `$('#new_message').val`. What is the name of `$('#new_message')` if there is none add one and then check in php if you have the value. Remember that ajax sends form data by names.

Comment: I have updated my code with php loop, so you can see how rows are generated.

Comment: @Krzysztof Janiszewski, I can see the value before AJAX, but can't get it in the PHP script. Yes, I have a name on that hidden field and same as iID(name="new_message").

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple elements with the same `id`. You should NOT do that. You check the value in jQuery and then send different form data.

This is all just quessing, I am unable to check it. But try changing `id` to `class` and make sure that you send the right form data.

For example change this

```html
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="update_qty.php">
```

to this

```js
<form name="form1" id="form<?= $sales_key; ?>" method="POST" action="update_qty.php">
```

Comment: OK, I got it. I addes class="message" and now is working. Only thing I can't figure out is why I get double entry in DB? Is there something wrong with jqueryonchange event or?

Comment: To many possibilities here. I can't help you more without being able to reproduce the problem and in case of php it is practically impossible.